# Backwards movement in Autoware 1.13

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Autoware 1.13 in ROS Melodic. I am using Gazebo for my car simulation and until now I have successfully managed to follow waypoints in a map using MPC and astar.
Specifically, I load the PCD map and the vehicle model in Autoware and then I enable the following modules from `Computing` tab:

```
  - ndt_matching
  - vel_pose_connect
  - lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect
  - costmap_generator
  - lane_rule
  - lane_stop
  - lane_select
  - waypoint_loader
  - astar_avoid 
  - velocity_set
  - mpc_follower
  - twist_filter
```

It works really well for waypoints that are in front of the car and can successfully follow them.
But, in some cases a maneuver may be needed and the car should go backwards for a while and then move forward again.

Does Autoware 1.13 give this option?

If yes, how is this achieved? Is there a special configuration needed for MPC to allow this movement?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357265/backwards-movement-in-autoware-1.13/) by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2020-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liyou zhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/47232/liyou-zhou/) on 2020-07-16**:
https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_planning/blob/6f74dfc7b2dfd1a20713ce24eb352debb981c833/freespace_planner/README.md might give a hint

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2020-07-16**:
The planner is providing me with waypoints that are backward movements. But the issue is that the car is not moving at all, the velocity commands sent to the topic remain 0

**Comment by [liyou zhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/47232/liyou-zhou/) on 2020-07-16**:
does pure_persuit node do backwards driving maybe? https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_planning/tree/6f74dfc7b2dfd1a20713ce24eb352debb981c833/pure_pursuit/src

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2020-07-17**:
I checked using Pure Pursuit as well, but the result is the same. Actually, as far as I understood from the code, pure pursuit finds that `can_get_curvature` is 0 in these kind of paths and as a result the twist command sent is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, this feature was started as part of 1.13.0 but was never competed. See https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/core_planning/-/issues/8 (archived) for more details about what was competed and what still needs work. We are happy to accept merge requests to compete this feature but I do not believe it is being actively worked on at this time.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0